# Android: Softkeyboard moving TextEdit out of screen

Tags: android

I am trying to the softkeyboard so the user can enter his information to create a new account on my android app. The problem is that some of my TextEdits are always flowing outside the screen and the user can not see what he actually typed. The screen looks this way:

[image: screenshot]

This screen was built using the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">     

    <com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar 
       android:id="@+id/actionbar" 
       style="@style/ActionBar"/>      

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPassword" 
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:singleLine="true" />

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPassword" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtName"/>

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtName" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPin"  /> 

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPin" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Pin"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" />            

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip" >    

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:text="@string/btnLogin"                     
        android:onClick="onRegisterClick" />                            

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml I have defined my Activity this way:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.NewAccountActivity" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

I have tried my different combinations of layout and windowSoftInputMode, but i never can get the TextEdit that is being changed to be visible on the screen. Am I missing anything here?

Thanks for any reply
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `adjustPan` to keep the field inside the visible area on the screen:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

---

**Update**:

Try not using `View` outside of `ScrollView`. I've changed your layout to have one top-level `ScrollView` and inner `LinearLayout`. All other elements are located inside `LinearLayout`. That's because Android does not know how to scroll `ScrollView` correctly when adjusting the screen for soft keyboard.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNumber" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPassword" 
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:singleLine="true" />

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPassword" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtName"/>

       <EditText android:id="@+id/txtName" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtPin"  /> 

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtPin" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Pin"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" />  

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dip" 
          android:orientation="vertical">    

          <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

              <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="login"                     
                  android:onClick="onRegisterClick" />                            

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>  

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thats they way the screen looks when I set adjustPan. When the focus in on the last exittext, the keyboard is over it. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/deviceq.png/

Answer (score 4):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add this line in your activity tag.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

like this

```
<activity android:name=".activity.NewAccountActivity" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"/>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: This cause the soft keyboard to be displayed over the fields and they are not scrolled up to the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You're scrollview is set to fill_parent, doesnt this cause clipping vertically of your controls? If you want it to stretch vertically, set the layout_height to 0dip.

You might also want to try replacing the activity's `windowSoftInputMode` and replace `adjustResize` with `adjustPan`

Comment: I have just tried this. Same thing, if I set the focus to the Phone Number editext, it goes out of screen and i cant see what i am typing. Thank you